# Intent.ACTION_VIEW and subclassing android.net.Uri

Tags: android, uri, action, inputstream

In my application I need to view some data which are accessible with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. Problem is in simple fact that I can't pass to ACTION_VIEW Intent Uri of my data, since data not in file or net resource - they're in encrypted database. I need to either subclass `android.net.Uri` or find a way and teach ACTION_VIEW accept instead of Uri just simple InputStream. But:

1. android.net.Uri can't be subclassed, since Uri() constructor is private
2. Intent.ACTION_VIEW accepts only `Uri` as data (does it?)

Any ideas how to solve issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "data" is "in encrypted database", then you have to write your own activity to view that data. Since it is your own activity, it will be able to access the "encrypted database".

Comment: Yea, that's an option, but I would like to use built-in viewers, because data mime types can be different and I can't (and I don't want) to rewrite all possible viewers. Probably there are some ways how to have hooks/callback to available viewers and transfer them decrypted data?

Comment: @barmaley: Not really. You could expose a content provider that gives them decrypted access, but then anyone can access the content provider, defeating the value of your encryption. Or, you could write the decrypted file to a file and give them a `Uri` to it, but then anyone can get to that file if they guess the path.

Comment: I have already did 2nd - I'm decrypting then saving to temporary file, but in this case there's security breach - temp file can be later restored (look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448772/safely-wipe-file-content). How about 1st option: could explain a bit more in details how to realize it? Thanx in advance

Comment: @barmaley: The 1st option is far less secure than the 2nd option. The only truly secure option is for you to write your own viewers.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Anyway how to expose content provider? I'd like to investigate this option, probably I'd find secure way

Comment: @barmaley: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html